# How to detemine if jekyll running locally or in production site?

Tags: jekyll

There is a config param in jekyll called production_url. I can't find any information on how to use it.

Ideally i would like to be able to generate permalinks with local url when it is being run with `serve` param  and with production url when run with `build` param.

How could I do that?

Comment: Why can't you use relative links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jekyll serve` will call `jekyll build`, so you can't really use those two as a way to output different URL schemes.

I built a Jekyll plugin that does this with a **Liquid Filter** and one user defined variable in your `_config.yml` called `mode`.

You set the `mode` to **development** or **production** and the plugin takes care of the rest in your templates.

So in your template you could have a URL such as:

```
<img src="{{ '/img/dog.jpg' | to_absurl }}" />
```

When `mode` is **development**, upon Jekyll build/serve you will get a **relative** URL:

```
<img src="/img/dog.jpg" />
```

Locally this would be accessed as: `http://0.0.0.0:4000/img/dog.jpg`

When `mode` is **production**, upon Jekyll build/serve you will get an **absolute** URL:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.tld/img/dog.jpg" />
```

The `http://www.domain.tld` is what you have set in `_config.yml` -> `url` variable.

You can see more details on the plugin here:

http://jhaurawachsman.com/2013/jekyll-url-helper-filter-plugin/

Comment: This is fairly convoluted.  Tommsy64's answer of checking jekyll.environment == "production" works perfectly well and is clean.

Answer (score 29):

When you build your Jekyll website, it’s possible to specify the environment it’s using for the build with the [`JEKYLL_ENV`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) environment variable:

```
$ JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
```

If you don’t set `JEKYLL_ENV` explicitly, it defaults to development.

```
{% if jekyll.environment == "production" %}
    // Production environment.
{% endif %}
```

Github Pages automatically sets the environment to production.

Comment: Note that Netlify *doesn't* set this automatically; you'll need to add it in *Site Settings → Build and Deploy → Environment*

Answer (score 26):

I don't see the variable production_url in the current release (v1.4.1), so this may be a dated question--but I was just looking for this answer myself. There is a baseurl property that can be set with a flag and so to change the path to your files, but it only adjusts the relative path.

```
jekyll serve --baseurl '/blog'
```

What you can do is to use the -config option to specify a configuration file for development.

[Jekyll Documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)

Your production configuration variables are defined in _config.yml. One option is to create a separate configuration file for development.

```
--config _config-dev.yml
```

You can also (as I do) override variables defined in a second configuration file.

```
--config _config.yml,_config-dev.yml
```

If you use the liquid templates for site links like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.base_url }}/stylesheets/blog.css">
```

then you can override the base_url property during local devlopment

```
base_url:           http://localhost:4000
```

and run jekyll in "Development"

```
jekyll serve -w --config _config.yml,_config-dev.yml
```

Comment: Great idea with using an override configuration file. I created a _config-dev.yml override file, put "mode:development" in it, and it works perfectly to define when I am in development mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This also worked for me:

```
$ JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll serve
```

Comment: If you define a custom build.command in your `netlify.toml`, e.g. `sh netlify.sh`, then you can prepend the jekyll command as suggested with `JEKYLL_ENV=...` easily.