# How can I easily manage different base URL of Jekyll webpage on localhost and remote server?

Tags: jekyll

On my computer, I access my test webpage on URL `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. On server, it will be on GitHub pages, that means `https://username.github.io/repo-name/`.

In the `_config.yml` I see following relevant settings:

```
# Uncomment if you are planning to run the blog in a subdirectory
# Note - if you enable this, and attempt to view your site locally you have to use the baseurl in your local path.
# Example, you must use http://localhost:4000/path/to/blog
#baseurl: /path/to/blog 
baseurl: 

# The URL of your actual domain. This will be used to make absolute links in the RSS feed.
url: http://yourdomain.com/
```

So for GitHub server I need it to be:

```
baseurl: /repo-name/
url: https://username.github.io/
```

But on localhost, it must be:

```
baseurl: 
url: http://127.0.0.1:4000
```

These settings are necessary because without them, I will get 404 errors for resources that are using relative paths:

```
<script src="js/ghapi.js"></script>
```

> `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://127.0.0.1:4000/download/js/ghapi.js"`

The path should be `http://127.0.0.1:4000/js/ghapi.js` but since the page was `/download` it was added to relative URL of the script file.

I need to deal with this issue, how do I do that?

Comment: Would be another config.yml for the local development defined as a serve parameter a solution for you? There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20587233/1456318) on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change site.url to localhost during jekyll local development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386169/change-site-url-to-localhost-during-jekyll-local-development)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best solution was to have two config files. The additional one, `debug.yml`, overrides some settings from the basic one. Both setting files can be loaded using this command:

```
jekyll serve --config _config.yml,debug.yml
```

The debug file can contain:

```
name: MySite [DEBUG MODE]
debug: true
url: http://127.0.0.1:4000
```

The advantage here is that no setting files need to be changed, you just use different command to run jekyll.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best option is having in `config.yml` the `baseurl` used in Github pages and when you launch your site locally, override this value with an empty one:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --baseurl=
```

That way, the site will work on localhost and in ghpages.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a branch and change url line in config.yml
url: http://127.0.0.1:4000